# How to proof that $\Phi(-x)=-\Phi(x)$ for Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have been studying the normal distribution and frequently I see that $\Phi(-x)=1-\Phi(x)$
and I can proof it with the integral.

Otherwise, I reached out that $\Phi(-x)=-\Phi(x)$, is there any chance to prove it?

I have tried but there is nothing$\ldots$

Comment: It's not possible for both those claims to hold.  Together they imply that $0=1$.

Comment: Perhaps it would clarify things if you shared what you meant by $\Phi(x)$.  If you meant the cumulative distribution function for the standard normal distribution, then the first claim you make holds, but obviously the second doesn't (how could a cumulative distribution function be negative?)

Comment: Almost surely means the normal distribution, @Lulu https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2133315/whats-this-mathematical-symbol#:~:text=Φ%20and%20ϕ%20are%20two,re%20reading%20anything%20on%20probability.&text=%2D%20that%20is%2C%20Φ%3DF,(x%E2%88%92μσ).

Comment: @Chickenmancer  Well, one would think, but then the claim that it is an odd function is bizarre.

Comment: @lulu normal distribution as I've mentioned

Comment: Be precise.  Which normal distribution?  What is the mean, what is the variance?  And do you mean the density function?  The cumulative distribution function? Something else?  Again, $\Phi$ is conventionally used for the cumulative distribution function, but how could you think that that could take negative values?

Comment: the standard normal form of the distribution Φ(). It was an article about that. That's why I've asked that I couldn't understand why it said Φ(-x)=−Φ(x)

Comment: Neither the cumulative distribution (which satisfies your first claim) nor the density (which satisfies $\phi(-x)=\phi(x)$) can take negative values, so neither satisfies the second claim.

Comment: For a standard normal (mean $0$, variance $1$), you would commonly say $\Phi(-x)=1-\Phi(x)$ for the CDF  and $\phi(-x)=\phi(x)$ for the density. Both $\Phi(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ need to be non-negative. Something similar can be said for  any random variable with an absolutely continuous distribution symmetric about $0$.

Comment: @Anastasia please rewrite your question no that you've received clarification in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by $\Phi$ the cumulative distribution function, then $\Phi(-x)=1-\Phi(x)$ holds. Recall that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$ \Phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{-\frac{s^2}{2}}ds.$$

Then by using integration by substitution ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution)),
\begin{align}
1- \Phi(x) &= 1- \int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{-\frac{s^2}{2}}ds \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{s^2}{2}}ds - \int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{-\frac{s^2}{2}}ds \\
&= \int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{s^2}{2}}ds  \\
&= \int_{-x}^{-\infty}e^{-\frac{(-t)^2}{2}}(-1)dt & \text{ substitute $s=-t$ }\\
&= -\int_{-x}^{-\infty}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt  \\
&= - \left(- \int_{-\infty}^{-x}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt\right)& \text{ switch bounds of integral} \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{-x}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt \\
&= \Phi(-x).
\end{align}